Prove that tensor product is associative
I wished to prove that tensor product is associative in the sense that

Given three finite-dimensional real vector spaces $X,Y,Z$,  there exists a unique linear isomorphism $F:X\otimes  Y\otimes  Z\rightarrow (X\otimes  Y)\otimes  Z$ that satisfy
\begin{align*}
F(x\otimes  y \otimes  z)=(x\otimes  y)\otimes  z
\end{align*}

and I came up with a "proof", which goes as follows

Define $f:X\times Y \times Z\rightarrow (X\otimes  Y)\otimes Z$ by
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z)\triangleq (x \otimes  y)\otimes z
\end{align*}
It follows from the universal property that there exists a unique linear map $F:X\otimes  Y\otimes Z\rightarrow (X \otimes  Y)\otimes  Z $ such that
\begin{align*}
F(x\otimes  y\otimes  z)=f(x,y,z)= (x \otimes y) \otimes z 
\end{align*}
It remains to show $F$ is bijective.  For all $z\in Z$, define $h_z:X\times Y\rightarrow X \otimes  Y\otimes Z$ by
\begin{align*}
h_z(x,y)\triangleq x\otimes  y\otimes  z
\end{align*}
If follows from the universal property that there exists a unique linear map $H_z:X\otimes  Y \rightarrow X \otimes  Y\otimes  Z$ such that
\begin{align*}
H_z(x \otimes  y)=h_z(x,y)=x \otimes  y \otimes  z
\end{align*}
Define $h:(X\otimes  Y)\times Z\rightarrow X\otimes Y \otimes Z$ by
\begin{align*}
h(v,z)\triangleq H_z(v)
\end{align*}
It follows from the universal property that there exists a unique linear map $H:(X\otimes  Y)\otimes  Z\rightarrow X\otimes Y\otimes Z$ such that
\begin{align*}
H((x\otimes y)\otimes z)=h(x\otimes  y,z)=H_z(x\otimes  y)=x\otimes  y\otimes  z
\end{align*}
Let $\otimes:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow X\otimes  Y\otimes  Z$ denotes the tensor product, we now have
\begin{align*}
\otimes = H \circ F \circ \otimes 
\end{align*}
It then follows from the universal property that $H \circ F=\textbf{id}: X\otimes  Y\otimes  Z\rightarrow X\otimes  Y\otimes  Z$. This implies $F$ is indeed bijective.

The reason I air quoted the word "proof" is that I think my proof is not complete, since we didn't really prove that $h:(X\otimes Y) \times Z \rightarrow X \otimes Y \otimes Z$ is indeed linear in $Z$, a property we immediately used after defining $h$.
Personally, I can convince myself that $h$ is indeed linear in $Z$ by giving $X\otimes Y$ the standard basis. Yet, I believe that the whole proposition holds true even in the context of modules, and I also know that it is possible for modules to not have a basis. This seems to suggest that there is a way to show $h$ is linear without resorting to basis elements, but I can't think of it. Can you help me find a way to show $h$ is linear without resorting to basis elements? If you believe we must resort to basis elements, also let me know why. Thanks in advance for your help in all forms.

This follows directly from the  universal property for a multilinear mapping that defines the tensor product $X \otimes Y \otimes Z$. If $f: X \times Y \times Z \to \Omega$ then there exists a linear map $\bar{f}:X \otimes Y \otimes Z\to\Omega$. Replace $\Omega$ with $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$; show that $\bar{f}$ is injective. Then given that $X,Y,Z$ are finite-dimensional $X \otimes Y \otimes Z \cong (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$.

It's easy to show by trilinearity of $(x, y, z) \mapsto x \otimes y \otimes z$ that $h_z(x, y)$ is linear in $z$.  As a consequence,
both $H_{c_1z_1 + c_2z_2}$ and $c_1H_{z_1} + c_2H_{z_2}$ are linear maps $F : X \otimes Y \to X \otimes Y \otimes Z$ satisfying
$F(x \otimes y) = h_{c_1z_1 + c_2z_2}(x, y) = c_1h_{z_1}(x, y) + c_2h_{z_2}(x, y)$
so by the uniqueness part of the universal property, they are equal.  This shows $H_z$ is linear in $z$, which means $h$ is linear in $z$.

The "linearity of $\otimes$" is useful for $x\otimes (z+z')=x \otimes z + x \otimes z'$. Here you use $x \otimes y \otimes (z+z')$ but this only works if $x \otimes y \otimes (z+z')= (x \otimes y) \otimes (z+z')$ which is what we are trying to prove.

@Ted Black By "linearity of $\otimes$" I just mean the fact that the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto x \otimes y \otimes z$ is trilinear (i.e. linear in each of its arguments), which is part of the definition of tensor product.  I edited the answer to make this more clear.

You are correct that nothing here needs to use bases. More generally, no basic property about how the tensor product  behaves, such as its commutativity and associativity up to isomorphism or its distributivity over direct sums up to isomorphism, needs bases.
Concerning your particular questions, see Theorems 5.2 and 5.6 here, where Theorem 5.2 builds an isomorphism between the modules $(M \otimes N) \otimes P$ and $M \otimes (N \otimes P)$ and Theorem 5.6 presents a general result about collapsing a function of several modules that is bilinear in two when the rest are fixed to a function where those two modules have been replaced in the domain by their tensor product.
A typo: your target in $h_z$ is meant to be $X \otimes Y \otimes Z$, not $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$.

Theorems 5.2 and 5.6 are very elegant. But once we have established that there exists a linear map $F(x \otimes y \otimes z)=(x \otimes y) \otimes z$ can't we establish the isomorphism simply by proving that $F$ is injective? $\dim X \otimes Y \otimes Z = \dim (X \otimes Y) \otimes Y$ so if it is injective it is also surjective. And we can prove that it is injective since $(x \otimes y) \otimes z=0 \iff x \otimes y \otimes z=0$.

I have edited the post correcting the typo. Thanks.

@TedBlack when working with finite-dimensional vector spaces, injectivity implies surjectivity if the dimensions are equal. But with modules, even finite free modules, injectivity does not generally imply surjectivity: consider $L : \mathbf Z^n \to \mathbf Z^n$ by $L(v) = 2v$.  Separately, injectivity can't be checked just by looking at what happens on the elementary tensors, even with tensor products of vector spaces: see Remark 4.17 and Example 5.19 in my link.

I have studied Theorem 5.2 in the link you provided. Am I correct in thinking that if I used it to show that $X \otimes Y \otimes Z \cong (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$ I would start from $f:X \times Y \times Z \to (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$, then there exists a linear map $\bar f:X \otimes Y \otimes Z \to (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$ and then given a bilinear map $g:(X \otimes Y) \times Z \to X \otimes Y \otimes Z$ there exists a linear map $\bar g:(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z \to X \otimes Y \otimes Z$. Since $\bar g$ is the inverse of $\bar f$ we have established the isomorphism.

@TedBlack technically Theorem 5.2 gives an isomorphism between $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$ and $X \otimes (Y \otimes Z)$, with no mention being made there of a threefold tensor product $X \otimes Y \otimes Z$ without parentheses. But if you are asking about using the idea in the proof of Theorem 5.2 to prove an  isomorphism between $X \otimes Y \otimes Z$ and $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$ , then yes you would build linear maps between these two tensor products and show their composition in each order is the identity.

Yes exactly my comment is about using the idea. I just do not understand why Theorem 5.2 has the intermediate step with bilinear map $b_p$ and corresponding linear map $f_p$. We should be able to go directly to $(M \otimes N) \times P \to M \otimes (N \otimes P)$ which generates linear map $(M \otimes N) \otimes P \to M \otimes (N \otimes P)$.

If you think we should, then please define what the bilinear map $(M \otimes N) \times P \to M \otimes (N \otimes P)$ is: where does the pair $(t,p)$ go, where $t$ is a general element  in $M \otimes N$ and $p \in P$?  Keep in mind most elements in $M \otimes N$ are not elementary tensors and your definition can't assume the map is already bilinear or even biadditive since here you are defining a map that should be proved to be bilinear.  The way I did it at that link takes advantage of having already shown $f_p(t)$ is bilinear in $t$ and $p$.

OK, finally, I get it. Given an element $t \in M \otimes N$, I cannot (always) write it as $t=m \otimes n$ so that then I can define $q(t,p)=m \otimes n \otimes p$. So we must go through the intermediate step of $b_p: M \times N \to M \otimes (N \otimes P)$ (and the corresponding linear map $f_p$) to end up with $f:(M \otimes N) \otimes P \to M \otimes (N \otimes P)$.

@TedBlack If you try to define $q$ on $(M\otimes N) \times P$ your way, when $t = \sum_{i=1}^k m_i \otimes n_i$ and $p \in P$, then set  $q(t,p) = \sum_{i=1}^k m_i \otimes (n_i \otimes p)$, but a problem remains: $q(t,p)$ may depend on how $t$ is written as a sum of elementary tensors, so you need to check that if $t$ is written in two ways as a sum of elementary tensors, say $t=\sum_{i=1}^k m_i \otimes n_i = \sum_{j=1}^\ell m_j' \otimes n_j'$, then you need to show $\sum_{i=1}^k m_i \otimes (n_i \otimes p) = \sum_{i=1}^\ell m_j'\otimes(n_j'\otimes p)$. It's easier to proceed as in the link.
